# pjax prevents using $app->response->sendFile in Controller

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

Following code

```
 $completePath = Yii::getAlias('@pictures' . '/' . $filename);
 return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($completePath, $filename);
```

will do its job if I code GridView without pjax. If I use pjax like this:

```html
 <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider_vermieten,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumn_vermieten,
        'pjax' => true, //this code prevents rendering pdf
        'pjaxSettings' => ['options' => ['id' => 'kv-pjax-container-immobilien']],
        'panel' => [
            'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
            'before' => Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> zur Hauptseite', ['/site/index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']),
            'after' => Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Reset Grid', ['/immobilien/index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'title' => 'Setzt die GridView zurück']),
            'heading' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>  ' . Html::encode($this->title),
        ],
        // your toolbar can include the additional full export menu
        'toolbar' => [
            ['content' =>
                Html::a('<i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>', ['/immobilien/index', 'bez' => 'umbenennen'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'title' => 'additional content'])
            ],
            '{export}',
            '{toggleData}'
        ],
        'toggleDataOptions' => ['minCount' => 10],
    ]);
    ?>
```

pdf file won't be rendered. Any ideas, how to render pdf-file using pjax in spite of everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by my own:
Following code will do its job using pjax,too:

```
 return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>', ['/immobilien/show', 'filename' => $filename], ['title' => 'Dokument anzeigen', 'data' => ['pjax' => '0']]);
```